# About the inverse of a function $f$ with integral

Tags: calculus, integration, inverse

I'm having a lot of trouble finding the inverse of this function, I'm not quite sure even where to begin with..

$$f(x) = x\sqrt{1-x^2} + 2\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-t^2} \, dt$$

Dom is $\mathbb R$.

Could you guys offer help?

Comment: Well you have $f(x) = x\sqrt{1 - x^2} + C$...in a simple minded case this equates to solving for $y$ in $x = y\sqrt{1 - y^2} + C$ which can be done using the quadratic formula, I believe.

Comment: The last integral does not contain $x$ and is equal to $\dfrac \pi 2$. Are you sure that this is what you mean? You should also give us a domain of definition and a range for $f$, otherwise this question risks being closed.

Comment: Thanks, added domain of the func, but what do you mean by range of $f$ ?

Comment: No, the domain cannot be $\Bbb R$: for instance, if $x = 2$, the quantity under the square root is negative and I believe that you do not want this. I believe the domain of $f$ to be a subinterval of $[-1,1]$.

Comment: The domain clearly must be $1 - x^2 \geq 0 \rightarrow x^2 \leq 1 \rightarrow -1 \leq x \leq 1$.  Otherwise, you open yourself up to complex functions which are very difficult to handle and the domain and range must be very specifically defined.

Answer (score 0):

The integral is a constant, so I will denote it with $C$. You have
$$y=x\sqrt{1-x^2}+C$$
$$y-C=x\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
$$(y-C)^2=x^2*(1-x^2)$$
$$(y-C)^2=x^2-x^4$$
Substitue $u=x^2$.
$$u^2-u+(y-C)^2=0$$

From there, use the quadratic formula to get your answer, and then fix the domain and range so that everything is real, unless you want it to be complex.